# Which is preferred oldest browser and shortest Screen Size of mobile to test website and which has Facility to surf Internet and still in use?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, mobile-website

Which is oldest browser and shortest Screen Size of mobile which has Facility to surf Internet and still in use?

I'm making a Mobile site for Older devices (Not for Smartphones), which are still in use.

I'm testing on [Nokia 5130 Xpress Music mobile](http://www.fonearena.com/nokia-5130-xpressmusic_726.html) which has size of 240 x 320 pixels and Browser is Opera Mini (Version I don't know).

Is it enough to test on this, these days or I should test on lower size than this and less capable browser than this?

Any suggestion?

[image]

**Edit:** Like in desktop we don't consider screen size lower than 1024 X 768 px and We have started to not to consider IE6, Firefox 2 and 3.0 etc.

**So is there any criteria like this for Screen and Browser for Mobile phones?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [what devices are used for surf Internet](http://trends.openstat.ru/global-statistic-devices/#level=2&attr=1%252C2%252C3) (sorry for Russian, that site doesn't seem to have English UI - but it's pretty self-explanatory) - you'll probably be amazed how many people still use "feature phones" with fairly small screens and Opera Mini (Java ME-based) to surf. While touch-based smartphones (such as iPhone) slowly grow, more than  50-60% of total mobile users still use fairly small screens and simple devices.

Comment: But I think "feature phones" users don't use internet much like smartphones users

Comment: In that list is any mobile having smaller screen then `240 x 320`?

Comment: Indeed, they do: take a look at the table. It's aggregated data from majority of Openstat's counters, which are in turn placed on many popular sites.

Comment: +1 Thanks - What is the lowest screen size and least capable browser in the list? any clue?

Comment: By the way, there might be some catches for 240x320 vs 320x240: some phones are oriented in only one way (say, "album") and thus you'll get width = 320px, but fairly short height.

Comment: I'm not considering height. I only want to know what can be the shortest width on any mobile in the list. I think I will have to check specifications of every mobile on google

Comment: Lowest screen size seems to be 176x220 pixels (SonyEricsson K750i, K550i), although their usage is declining. So, basically, for a rule of thumb, if you care only about widths, you should support 240px width (if you care for 2007+ phones) and 176px width (if you care for 2005+ phones).

Comment: @GreyCat - And which browser will be oldest in this list? any clue

Comment: Majority of "feature phones" use Opera Mini. There are a few of ancient mobile browsers, such as "NetFront", "UCWEB", "Obigo", "Openwave" and other variations. For percentages, see http://trends.openstat.ru/global-statistic-browsers/ (note that that percentages are for _all_ users, not just _mobile_ users, as in mobile devices report I've cited before).

Answer (score -2):

There are really a bunch of crap mobile phones that come accompanied with crap browsers as well.

Its smarter to test for the better mobile browsers instead for the worst or oldest in use. Make em look great on the iPhone and Android. Min res of 320x480 ( anything below this is just not worth the trouble.)

And for the rest -they will gracefully (more or less) degrade.

For features on the most important mobile browsers you can use http://caniuse.com/ or http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/

Comment: It's not answer of my question. it's clearly mentioned in questions "I'm making a Mobile site for Older devices (Not for Smartphones)"